# Django AttributeError 'Tag' object has no attribute 'summary'

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, attributeerror

I run into this error whenever I tried to add a new Tag. I tried to google and read some SO posts, but nothing work for me.

Here are my 2 models :

Summary :

```
class Summary(models.Model):

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url = models.URLField(null=False)
    cover_image = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', related_name='summaries', blank=True)
    userProfileSummary = models.ManyToManyField('UserProfile', through='UserProfileSummary')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Summaries"
```

Tag :

```
class Tag(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

models/**init**.py:

```
...
from .tag import Tag
from .summary import Summary


__all__ = (
     ...
    'Tag',
    'Summary',
)
```

Error :
[image]

Please, what did I miss ?

Comment: are your migrations proper?. can you show it admin panel?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your code. Have you made migrations and actually migrated them? As for your `created_at` field, try Googling `TimeStampedModel`. Also have a look at `django-taggit`

Comment: Yes. I used those 2 command lines to migrates :  `./manage.py makemigrations ` and then  `./manage.py migrate `

Comment: You have to put Tag Model Before Summary Model, Then it works..

Comment: I don't think so. As long as the ForeignKey name is a string that should work. Try installing `django-extensions`, then run `manage.py reset_db`. Delete your migrations. Remake them then give it another try

Comment: @ShihabudheenKM no it doesn't work (I edited my post)

Comment: @Parousia it has changed nothing. Still get the error :(

Comment: Kinda strange. Try @Shihabudheen's suggestion of reordering the models. But why the imports in your `__init__.py` file?

Comment: Because I organized my model into a piece of file. Each model (tag, summary) has its own file